# unity c# issue unable to get perfect position of a enemy in unity c# script using transform.position

Tags: unity, c#

when I command or set an enemy to go left and then at reaching a particular state or position i say my enemy to go right but it is not going right and not reaching to perfect position here is the code I think there is no issue in the code but it is not working properly so here are some images of the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enem : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-3f, 0f, 0f)* 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        if (transform.position.x > -29)
        {
            transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(3f, 0f, 0f) * 1 * Time.deltaTime;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I think there is no issue with the code" and "it is not working properly" are in contradiction. If the code you wrote is not achieving the outcome you want, then *you wrote the wrong code*. Try explaining in more detail what you need here. 1) Where does your character start? 2) Which direction should they move at first? 3) When they reach that location, what should they do? Stop there, or change direction? 4) And then what happens - if they stopped, do they stop forever? If they changed direction, do they keep going in the new direction forever?

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is:

1. The object moves left while its position is larger than -29.
2. Then it notices that its over the -29 mark and moves to the right for one frame
3. But on the very next frame, its position is larger than -29 again, so it moves left again

So the object keeps oscilating around the -29 point.

What you need is:

1. a variable to store the information whether the object is in the "move-left" state or the "move-right" state
2. two checks to see if the condition for changing direction is true and if so change the value of the variable
3. Move the object left or right depending on the value of the variable.